# Why does unboxing lose margin kerning in pdfTeX?

Tags: pdftex, boxes, plain-tex, protrusion

Consider the following code:

```
\showboxdepth=20
\showboxbreadth=200
\hsize=5.33333in
\pdfoutput=0

\pdfprotrudechars=1 
\input protcode.tex
\setprotcode\tenrm


\vbox{\noindent  Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test.
Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test.
Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test.\par
\global\setbox3=\lastbox }
\showbox3 \setbox3=\hbox{\unhbox3 }%
\showbox3

\bye
```

Now run it with `pdftex`. The log file shows that the left and right margin `\kern`s disappear in reboxing. Why? Can it be prevented? Here are excerpts:

```
> \box3=
\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x385.43962, glue set 3.85056fil
.\kern-0.36 (left margin)
.\tenrm T
.\kern-0.83334
.\tenrm e
.\tenrm s
.\tenrm t
.\tenrm .
.\glue 4.44444 plus 4.99997 minus 0.37036
[cut]
.\tenrm T
.\kern-0.83334
.\tenrm e
.\tenrm s
.\tenrm t
.\tenrm .
.\penalty 10000
.\kern-1.94 (right margin)
.\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\glue(\rightskip) 0.0


! OK.
l.15 \showbox3 
               \setbox3=\hbox{\unhbox3 }%
? 
> \box3=
\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x383.88907
.\tenrm T
.\kern-0.83334
.\tenrm e
.\tenrm s
.\tenrm t
.\tenrm .
[cut]
.\tenrm T
.\kern-0.83334
.\tenrm e
.\tenrm s
.\tenrm t
.\tenrm .
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\glue(\rightskip) 0.0

! OK.
l.16 \showbox3
```

This won't happen with ordinary `\kern`s, such as if we `\setbox3=\hbox{\kern-1pt Test.\kern1pt}`.

Comment: I'm afraid this is “by design”.

Comment: I believe this is related to the loss in pdfLaTeX if you use **microtype**: you lose protrusion in the headings of sections, for example. (You can get it back in a specific case, but you can't really compensate for all the eventualities which have the same effect.)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262987/microtype-protrusion-not-affecting-unnumbered-section-titles (and probably earlier discussions - that's just the one I know and can find easily).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed, as @egreg has said in the comments, [by design](http://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-pdftex/2005-April/001129.html) (margin kerning is lost after `\unhbox`ing or `\unhcopy`ing). But there are two commands that come as remedy: `\leftmarginkern` and `\rightmarginkern` allow access to the the respective kerns of an `hbox`.

So to adapt your sample code, the following will reinsert margin kerning:

```
\showboxdepth=20
\showboxbreadth=200
\hsize=5.33333in
%\pdfoutput=0

\pdfprotrudechars=1
\input protcode.tex
\setprotcode\tenrm

\setbox0=\vbox{\noindent  Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test.
        Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test.
        Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test.\par}
\showbox0 

\newbox\splitbox
\setbox3=\vbox{%
  \loop\ifvbox0
    \vbadness=10000
    \splittopskip=0pt
    \setbox\splitbox\vsplit0 to\baselineskip
    \unvbox\splitbox\setbox\splitbox=\lastbox
    \hbox{\kern\leftmarginkern\splitbox
          \expandafter\unhbox\expandafter\splitbox\expandafter
          \kern\rightmarginkern\splitbox}%
  \repeat}

\showbox3
\unvbox3
\bye
```

(Mind you, there is bug with `\rightmarginkern` and stretchy `\parfillskip` as reported [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/240530/7674).)